# In the movie Avatar, mountains were floating on their own but vehicles needed engines to fly, why?

Tags: avatar

When Quaritch organizes a pre-emptive strike against the Tree of Souls, the mountains were floating on their own while the RDA vehicles needed engines to fly, why?

Comment: Related: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/9104/why-did-mountains-float-in-avatar?rq=1

Answer (score 40, accepted):

The [Hallelujah mountains](http://james-camerons-avatar.wikia.com/wiki/Hallelujah_Mountains) float because they're essentially large chunks of [unobtainium](http://james-camerons-avatar.wikia.com/wiki/Unobtanium), which is a room temperature [superconductor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superconductivity), thus subject to the Meissner Effect. This causes superconductors to "levitate" in the presence of certain strong magnetic fields:
[image: Image of a supercooled "high-temperature superconductor" levitating above a magnet.]

Vehicles need engines to fly because gravity and the laws of thermodynamics still exist in the Avatar universe. So vehicles still need a power source for propulsion and can't defy gravity for no apparent reason.

Comment: although - looking at the size of the shuttle in the movie, it must surely use some unobtainium to help with lift...

Comment: @HorusKol Nah, just some futuristic power supply with unheard-of energy density & some futuristic engines with unheard of thrust-to-weight ratios.